# What does that mean when we say Group in Liferay and what all does Group consists of? and its uses?

Tags: java, liferay

I am new to Liferay portal and was curious to know about the functioning of Group, Organizations. I went through few of online discussions but I did not get much information. Any explanation is helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Group** basically refers to Site in Liferay. Site can have set of pages and members. **UserGroup/User/Organization** can have pages and hence respective Group will be created for it.

**Liferay artifacts:**

- **Users**:
  Users are key entity in Liferay portal.
  In Liferay portal, users are associated with site / organization / usergroups. They have different roles
- **Site** (Till Liferay 6.0 this was know as Community): Liferay provides provision of Site.
  Site in Liferay represents web site that has page, content , users and other functionality.
  Generally any web site is comprises of set of static files (html) or it’s built by some web application. Liferay site provides similar functionality. It allows us to add pages, users, look and feel and other functionalities (portlets) to form a complete web site.
  Users in site can access different part and functionality of site based on site role associated.
- **Organization**: Organization in Liferay manages users in hierarchy.
  Organization can have a site so all functionality of sites are also applicable to organization.
- **Role** – Permission: Role in liferay define privileges to access certain pages or functionality.
  Permission is resource level priviledge. Group of permissions form a role in Liferay.
- **User Group**: user groups is used to group set to users with common interest.

Following are possible association between liferay artifacts.

- Liferay Portal has Users
- User can be part of Organization
- User can be part of Site
- Organization is used to aggregate users in hierarchical manner.
- Users with common interest can be part of same Site. It’s similar to face book group where people with common interest can collaborate with each other.
- Organizations can have Site but Site can’t have Organization
- User can have: Site Specific Roles;
  Organization specific Roles;
  Regular (Portal level) Roles;
- Each Role in Liferay is having set of Permissions.
- User Groups is collections of Users
- User Groups can be associated to Site
- User can be associated to Site, Organization and User Group

Relation between liferay artifacts (User, Organization, Site and User Group) can be explained by below screen shot.

[image: Relation between liferay artifacts (User, Organization, Site and User Group) can be explained by below screen shot.]

- User can have role. Roles are further scoped by Organization, Sites or Regular (Portal Level)
- Ex. User A can have Administrator role for Site-a but for Site-b he is just normal user.
- Each Role is group of Permissions.
- For each Site, there will be one role called Site Administrator which has full access for that site(Super User). Similar is applicable for Organization.
- Apart from Site and Organization Administrator, there is one more role called Site Owner and Organization Owner which is similar to Site / Organization Administrator.
- The only different between them is Site / Organization Owner can make other user Administrator for that Site / Organization while simple Administrator can’t do it.

Complete tutorial: https://www.opensource-techblog.com/complete-liferay-guide

More information on User Groups: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/user/-/knowledge_base/u/user-groups

More information on User Management: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/user/-/knowledge_base/u/user-management